# Get static readonly string value through dll using Mono.Cecil?

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

I have a cs code file such as:

```cs
public class Constants
{
    public static readonly string test="testcontent";
}
```

When I use Mono.Ceil parse the dll, I can't find the string `"testcontent"`.

I tested the api `Field.InitialValue` which is empty.

Then I write another test code.
Then I found the readonly string can be accessed by [ldsfld](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldsfld?view=netframework-4.7.2). But I have no idea how I can access it in code.

Then I checked all stuff by using `il dasm`.
I can't find the string anywhere.

If it can't be done, any clues will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static fields are initialized as part of static constructor or type initializers. When using `ildasm` you can find the string in `.cctor`

Comment: Somehow I neglect that. Thanks.